# How to pass quantity from component to component in ReactJS where they are independent but live in the same parent

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following class Component that is handling some quantity changes an updating the price of a sku from stripes API.

The crux of the issue is that I need the quantity for the sku inside the Cart component, but the quantity state is handled inside the Product component, and it needs to be separate because you can change the sku in the dropdown menu and the product will change state, so if the cart component is in the product then the state clears and is not persistent. Also I will need a way for the cart to add to the state instead of just replacing it on `setSkuObject` not sure if that's possible either

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Product component

```
  class Product extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props)
  
      this.state = {
        stripe: null,
        quantity: 1,
        price: props.price,
        skuObject: null,
      }
  
      this.handleInputChange = this.handleInputChange.bind(this)
    }
    
  
    handleInputChange(event) {
      const target = event.target
      const { quantity } = this.state
      const { price } = this.props
  
  
      this.setState({
        quantity: parseInt(target.value),
      })
      this.setState({
        price: price * parseInt(target.value),
      })
    }
  
    render() {
      const { id, currency, name, productId } = this.props
      const { quantity, price, skuObject } = this.state
  
      //console.log(quantity);
  
      const priceFloat = (price / 100).toFixed(2)
      const formattedPrice = Intl.NumberFormat("en-US", {
        style: "currency",
        currency,
      }).format(priceFloat)
  
      return (
        <>
          <form className="name-buy">
            <label>
              Quantity
              <input
                type="number"
                name="amount"
                min="1"
                value={this.state.quantity}
                onChange={this.handleInputChange}
              />
            </label>
          </form>
          <form
            className="submit"
            onSubmit={this.handleSubmit(id, productId, quantity)}
          >
            <div>
              <h2>
                {name} ({formattedPrice})
              </h2>
              <button type="submit">Buy Now</button>
            </div>
          </form>
        </>
      )
    }
  }
```

cart class component

```
class Cart extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      sku: null,
      quantity: null,
    }
  }
  render() {
    const { skuObject } = this.props
    return <CartBox>Cart {skuObject} {/*would like to have quantity here*/} </CartBox>
  }
}
```

It lives inside A StoreDetails functional component

```
const StoreDetails = ({ data, location }) => {
    const setSkuOnce = data.allDatoCmsStore.edges.map(
      ({ node: product }, index) => {
        if (product.defaultProduct === true) {
          //console.log(product.skuId);
          return product.skuId
        }
      }
    )
  
    //console.log(setSkuOnce)
  
    var filtered = setSkuOnce.filter(function(el) {
      return el != null
    })
  
    const [value, setValue] = useState({
      skuId: filtered[0],
    })
  
    const run = event => {
      //console.log(event);
      setValue({ skuId: event })
    }
  
    const [skuObject, setSkuObject] = useState()
    const handleCart = (sku, productId, quantity) => {
      return event => {
        event.preventDefault()
        setSkuObject(sku)
      }
    }
  
    return (
      <Layout>
        <StoreHero>
          <Link to="/store">
            <BsArrowLeft />
            Back
          </Link>
          <Alert test="test" hello="hello" hash={location.hash} />
  
          {/* <ShowItem props={data}/> */}
  
          <Cart skuObject={skuObject} />
  
          {data.allDatoCmsStore.edges.map(({ node: sku }) => (
            <React.Fragment key={sku.skuId}>
              {value.skuId === sku.skuId ? (
                <ProductGrid>
                  <Img fluid={sku.image.fluid} />
                  <ProductCol>
                    <h1>{sku.productTitle}</h1>
                    <FirstThreeWrap>
                      <form className="variant">
                        <label>
                          <span>Product Variant</span>
                          <select
                            value={value.skuId}
                            onChange={event => run(event.target.value)}
                          >
                            {data.allDatoCmsStore.edges.map(({ node: sku }) => (
                              <React.Fragment key={sku.skuId}>
                                <option value={sku.skuId}>{sku.title}</option>
                              </React.Fragment>
                            ))}
                          </select>
                        </label>
                      </form>
  
                      {/* <ShowItem setValue={setValue}/> */}
                      <Product
                        key={sku.id}
                        id={sku.skuId}
                        productId={sku.productId}
                        currency="cad"
                        price={sku.price}
                        name={sku.title}
                      />
                      <button onClick={handleCart(sku.skuId, sku.productId)}> {/* I NEED TO PASS THE QUANTITY IN HERE */}
                        Add to Cart
                      </button>
                    </FirstThreeWrap>
                    <div
                      className="description"
                      dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: sku.productDescription }}
                    />
                    <QuestionForm skuId={sku.skuId} name={sku.title} />
                  </ProductCol>
                </ProductGrid>
              ) : null}
            </React.Fragment>
          ))}
        </StoreHero>

      </Layout>
    )
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I've parsed all this correctly, then it would seem you could achieve it by simply moving the "Add To Cart" button inside `Product`. I can't see any reason not to as they are rendered one after the other and use exactly the same data from the map function. You would just pass the handler down like so:

```
<Product
  key={sku.id}
  id={sku.skuId}
  productId={sku.productId}
  currency="cad"
  price={sku.price}
  name={sku.title}
  handleCart={handleCart}
/>
```

And then in `Product` render it like this:

```
return (
  <>
    <form>
      ...
    </form>
    <button onClick={() => this.props.handleCart(id, productId, this.state.quantity)}>
      Add to Cart
    </button>
  </>
)
```

Comment: unfortunately, when I change a product in the dropdown menu it updates the state of the product component so anything inside the product component including the cart get wiped, I need the cart to persist when the product is changed in the dropdown menu. I mentioned I couldn't do you suggestion in my question, I had already tried this.

Comment: This part here determines the product `<select value={value.skuId} onChange={event => run(event.target.value)}>` and when it changes I need the cart to keep its state

Comment: so if the cart is in the product component and that select is changed the cart resets state. If it is in the parent component when that select value changes it persists which is what I want it to do.

Comment: I don't quite follow you - in my suggestion the `Cart` component isn't in the `Product` component, it's still in the parent. The only prop that the `Cart` component takes is `skuObject`, and the only function that updates `skuObject` is `handleCart`. The `skuObject` will persist if a `Product` is unmounted. You would need to do something with the `quantity` paramater it takes for `Cart` to recieve it. Edit: just noticed an issue, handleCart expects `sku` but in your example you pass it `sku.id`. You would have to pass the entire sku object to `Product`.

Comment: ok I think I understand now, your passing the values via props into the function. I will test out and then come back and pick your answer. Thanks